# pandas groupby and count if count less remove group and remaining add in new dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

i want to divide data in 10 minutes pieces and and count rows if less than 2 rows delete groups and combine remaining groups in one dataframe .

i already tried this but not sure how to remove groups with row count less than 2

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[5,5,4,6,1],'x2':[5,5,6,7,1],
                         'time':['11/7/2019 10:11','11/7/2019 10:14',
                                 '11/7/2019 10:16','11/7/2019 11:20',,'11/7/2019 11:27']}) 

df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']))

x=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10Min', base=30, label='right')).count()
```

Note: i know to use loop method , i dont want to use for loop

Traget output:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[5,5,4],'x2':[5,5,6],
                             'time':['11/7/2019 10:11','11/7/2019 10:14',
                                     '11/7/2019 10:16']})
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could use [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10Min', label='right'))
res = grouped.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
                     x1  x2             time
time                                        
2019-11-07 10:11:00   5   5  11/7/2019 10:11
2019-11-07 10:14:00   5   5  11/7/2019 10:14
2019-11-07 10:16:00   4   6  11/7/2019 10:16
```

As a side note, the *base* argument has been deprecated, and in your case you don't need it. From the documentation:

> Deprecated since version 1.1.0: The new arguments that you should use
> are ‘offset’ or ‘origin’.